# HTML events VS Javascript events

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, attributes

After a while I could not find a proper answer to this question: Is there any difference in using html events over javascript ones?

What I mean is, would it not be easier to maintain/change the code of a page with having all the javascript separately without using the html event attributes? Or is there any other possible reason for their usage?

Just a small snippet of what I mean (using the html event attribute)

```js
function addValue() {
    $("#clickButton").text(parseInt($("#clickButton").text())+1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id = "clickButton" onclick = "addValue()">0</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ""why were these attributes added in HTML 5" — They weren't.

Comment: Right, thanks for the link, I saw the topic name before, but did not think I would find what I was searching for there, maybe should give more time next time checking other similar topics if I can find an answer, sorry for the duplicate question.